# Getting 401 Unauthorized status code while hitting a SOAP API end point

Tags: ubuntu, soap, http-status-code-401

I am newbie to API's . I have received a soap api end point url from the client. This url, normally when hit on the chrome in windows operating system it shows the output, whereas if I try the same thing on the Ubuntu operating system it gives 401 Unauthorized. Can anybody help me to figure out what exactly the issue is . Do I need to download any software for this on my ubuntu system? How to make this work. Need help.

Answer (score 0):

If it is working on windows OS the authentication is getting handled automatically behind the scenes if you are on Domain Joined PC.

Is your ubuntu Domain joined?

One way you could track the differences is to download fiddler and check the communication.

Comment: What is joined domain? Also if you can share a link which has documentation on fiddler. Great thanks for answering.

Comment: When I meant Domain Joined I was assuming you are connected to work network on your PC's (windows and Ubuntu). If so, the authentication is handled automatically by your browser when a 401 is recieved. Here is a link to fiddler   https://www.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere